# Run tests in parallel using Cucumber with Java Selenium with Gradle

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, cucumber

I'm using Cucumber with Gradle and would like to run Cucumber features in parallel but can't figure out how. My cucumber executor looks like this:

```
task cucumber() {
dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
doLast {
    javaexec {
        main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
        classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
        args = ['--plugin', 'pretty',
                '--plugin', 'json:build/reports/cucumber-report.json',
                '--plugin', 'html:build/reports/cucumber-report.html',
                '--glue', 'stepDefinitions',
                'src/test/java']
        systemProperty "cucumber.options", System.getProperty("cucumber.options")
    }
}
```

}

Thanks, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit of setup needed to get cucumber running in parallel properly with gradle.

- Every test has to be threadsafe so you need to be careful with static usage.
- Multiple drivers need to be made for each thread
- logging needs to log the correct thread and scenario

> [I have a skeleton framework that handles all of this that you can use
> as a reference or build from here](https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton)

For your specific question in the **build.gradle** you determine the **--threads** cucumber option.

[Take a look in the build.gradle here](https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton/blob/f4be403e6fb00d78cc9b4175769b1b8b8177af91/build.gradle#L63)

These variables are used to setup parallel runs and determine threads to use in the **cucumber options**

```
def availableThreadCount = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) ?: 1
def cucumberThreadsOption = ['--threads', availableThreadCount.toString()]
```

if **runInParallel** task is used it puts **setParallel** to true. We then add the **--threads** arg into the cucumber options
[This is where that happens in the **cucumber** task](https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton/blob/master/build.gradle#L99)

[Here is where the built cucumber options are used](https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton/blob/f4be403e6fb00d78cc9b4175769b1b8b8177af91/build.gradle#L100)

[CreateSharedDrivers.java here](https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton/blob/master/src/test/java/core/setup/CreateSharedDrivers.java) is where we handle creating multiple drivers for threads and have the shutdown hook implemented.

In [Hooks.java here](https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton/blob/f4be403e6fb00d78cc9b4175769b1b8b8177af91/src/test/java/core/setup/Hooks.java#L68) there is an example of how we log the thread and its current scenario