# I need to run cucumber feature files in parallel using gradle

Tags: selenium, gradle, build.gradle, build-automation, gradle-plugin

I am working on automation which is based on  Cucumber, gradle. I am Unable to execute the feature files in parallel not sure what  needs to done. But I am able to run/execute feature files sequentially.

```
Can somebody please look into this issue and provide me some inputs.


**Below is my build.gradle file** 

        

    plugins {
            id 'java'
            id 'maven-publish'
            //id 'java-library'
            //id 'io.qameta.allure' version '2.8.1'
        
        }
        
        
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
        }
        
        task deleteGraphicsAssets(type: Delete) {
            delete "build"
        }
        
        task allureHistoryCopy() {
            mkdir "./allure-results/history"
            copy {
                from "./allure-report/history"
                into "./allure-results/history/"
            }
        }
        
        group 'com.hal.brands'
        version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        
            
        def cucumberVersion = '4.8.0'
        def gherkinVersion  = '5.1.0'
        def hamcrestVersion = '1.3'
        
        def testngVersion = '6.14.3'
        def cucumber4adapterVersion = '1.0.11'
        
        def Log4jVersion = '1.2.17'
        def slf4jVersion = '1.7.5'
        
        def restassuredVersion = '3.3.0'
        def jsonsimpleVersion = '1.1.1'
        
        def appiumjavaClientVersion = '7.3.0'
        
        def allurePluginVersion = '2.8.1'
        def allurecucumber4jvmVersion = '2.13.0'
        def codeborneselenideVersion = '5.3.1'
            
        
        dependencies {
        
            //All version of the dependencies are defined above
        
            //Cucumber
            testImplementation  "io.cucumber:cucumber-java:${cucumberVersion}"
            testImplementation  "io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm:${cucumberVersion}"
            testImplementation  "io.cucumber:cucumber-core:${cucumberVersion}"
            testImplementation  "io.cucumber:cucumber-testng:${cucumberVersion}"
        
            implementation  "io.cucumber:cucumber-picocontainer:${cucumberVersion}"  //Do not change from implementation to testImplementation otherwise Scenario will throw errors
        
            //Cucumber Gherkin
            testImplementation  "io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin:${gherkinVersion}"
        
            //Hamcrest
            testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:${hamcrestVersion}"
        
        
            //TestNg
            //testImplementation "org.testng:testng:${testngVersion}"
            //testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.13.1'
        
        
            //Cucumber Adapter Extent Reports
            //testImplementation  'com.aventstack:extentreports:4.0.9'   // Do not use this when you are using Cucumber Adapter Extent reports. Not Required when Adapter used
            testImplementation  "com.aventstack:extentreports-cucumber4-adapter:${cucumber4adapterVersion}"
        
        
            //Log4j Logs
            implementation "log4j:log4j:${Log4jVersion}"  //Do not change from implementation to testImplementation otherwise  PropertyConfigurator and Logger will throw errors
        
            //Rest Assured Apis
            testImplementation "io.rest-assured:rest-assured:${restassuredVersion}"
            testImplementation "com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:${jsonsimpleVersion}"
            testImplementation 'org.json:json:20180813'
        
        
            //Selenium Apis
            compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-server', version: '3.141.59'
            implementation 'com.paulhammant:ngwebdriver:1.1.4'
            compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-htmlunit-driver', version: '2.52.0'
            implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59'
        
        
            //Allure Reports
            testImplementation "io.qameta.allure:allure-cucumber4-jvm:${allurecucumber4jvmVersion}"
            implementation "io.qameta.allure:allure-selenide:${allurecucumber4jvmVersion}"
            implementation "com.codeborne:selenide:${codeborneselenideVersion}"
        
        
            //Appium
            implementation "io.appium:java-client:${appiumjavaClientVersion}"
        
        
            //Netty Jar is important
            compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-all', version: '4.1.31.Final'
        
            //AspectJweaver
            runtime group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.9.6'
        
            compile group: 'com.browserstack', name: 'browserstack-integration', version: '1.0.0'
            compile group: 'com.browserstack', name: 'browserstack-local-java', version: '0.3.0'
        
            //MongoDB
            // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver
            // compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver', version: '3.12.6'
            // compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver', version: '3.4.2'
        
            // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver
            compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.12.6'
        
            //SqlServer
            // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
            compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '7.2.1.jre8'
        
            // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple
            compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
        
        
        
            //SqlServer
            // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
            compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '7.2.1.jre8'
        
        
             compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'testng-6.14.3.jar')   //This should be last statement
           
        }
        
        
        configurations {
            cucumberRuntime.extendsFrom testImplementation
        }
        
        
        
        task runTest() {
            dependsOn assemble, testClasses
            doLast {
                javaexec {
                    main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
                    classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
        
                    systemProperty "environment", project.findProperty("env") ?: "QA"
                    systemProperty "platform", project.findProperty("plt")  ?: "browserstack"
                    
                    
        
                    args = [
        
                             '--threads' , '2',
                          
                          
                            '--plugin', 'pretty',
        
                            '--plugin', 'json:target/HAL.json',
        
                            //'--plugin', 'io.qameta.allure.cucumber4jvm.AllureCucumber4Jvm',
        
                            '--plugin', 'com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:Report',
        
                            '--glue',   'com.pros.InitDriver',
        
                            '--glue',   'com.pros.helper.Logger',
        
                            '--glue',   'com.pos.it.helper',
        
                            '--glue',   'com.bpos.test.stepdefinition',
        
                            '--glue',   'src/main/java','src/test/resources','src/main/resources',
        
                            '--tags',    project.findProperty("testTag")  ?: "@sanity"
        
                    ]
        
                }
        
            }
        }
        
         /*
        
            allure {
                System.setProperty( "user.dir", project.projectDir.toString() )
                version = allurePluginVersion
                autoconfigure = true
                aspectjweaver = true
                //boolean clean = true
                resultsDir = file("${project.projectDir}/allure-results");
                println "resultsDir : ${resultsDir}"
                reportDir = file("${project.projectDir}/allure-report");
                println "reportDir : ${reportDir}"
                String configuration = 'testImplementation'
                useTestNG {
                    version = '2.0-BETA10'
                }
                useCucumberJVM {
                    version = '2.0-BETA10'
                }
            }
        
           runTest.finalizedBy 'allureReport'
         */
        
        
        task packageZip(type: Zip){
        
        
            from "$project.rootDir/Automation_Report"
            print "$project.rootDir\n"
            destinationDir = file("$project.rootDir/Archive")
            Date date = new Date()
            String datePart = date.format("yyyyMMdd")
            String timePart = date.format("HHmmss")
            println "datePart : " + datePart + "\ttimePart : " + timePart
        
            archiveName = datePart+"_"+timePart+"_"+"IST.zip"
        
            //  archiveName = "datePart_timePart_IST.zip"
            println "Zip action complete"
        }
        
        
        
        
        tasks.test {
        
            // finalizedBy runTest
            finalizedBy packageZip
        
        }


**Below the sample command that I use in command prompt**
gradle runTest -PtestTag=@sanity_ui -Penv=STAGE -Pplt=Local

**Below is my project Hierarchy**

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

I am not sure as what  need to be included in args section in build.gradle file  so that it kicks of  parallel execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recent answer to this closely related question should be helpful here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65473008/10256045

> There is a bit of setup needed to get cucumber running in parallel
> properly with gradle.
>
> - Every test has to be threadsafe so you need to be careful with static usage.
> - Multiple drivers need to be made for each thread
> - logging needs to log the correct thread and scenario
>
> > [I have a skeleton framework that handles all of this that you can use
> > as a reference or build from here](https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton)
>
> For your specific question in the **build.gradle** you determine the
> **--threads** cucumber option.
>
> [Take a look in the build.gradle here](https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton/blob/f4be403e6fb00d78cc9b4175769b1b8b8177af91/build.gradle#L63)
>
> These variables are used to setup parallel runs and determine threads
> to use in the **cucumber options**
>
> ```
> def availableThreadCount = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors().intdiv(2) ?: 1
> def cucumberThreadsOption = ['--threads', availableThreadCount.toString()]
> ```
>
> if **runInParallel** task is used it puts **setParallel** to true. We
> then add the **--threads** arg into the cucumber options [This is
> where that happens in the **cucumber** task](https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton/blob/master/build.gradle#L99)
>
> [Here is where the built cucumber options are used](https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton/blob/f4be403e6fb00d78cc9b4175769b1b8b8177af91/build.gradle#L100)
>
> [CreateSharedDrivers.java here](https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton/blob/master/src/test/java/core/setup/CreateSharedDrivers.java) is where we handle creating
> multiple drivers for threads and have the shutdown hook implemented.
>
> In [Hooks.java here](https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton/blob/f4be403e6fb00d78cc9b4175769b1b8b8177af91/src/test/java/core/setup/Hooks.java#L68) there is an example of how we log the thread
> and its current scenario

Comment: Thanks for the update and info and i will definitely look into it and give my inference.

Comment: Can we integrate your framework with extent and allure reports

Comment: Can you please tell me where in can change /add the project name so that it gets displayed on the Actual Report

Comment: [for the reporting I use this plugin that you will have to follow and edit as needed for yourself.](https://gitlab.com/monochromata-de/cucumber-reporting-plugin)
---
[You can see that added in here within the project](https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton/blob/f4be403e6fb00d78cc9b4175769b1b8b8177af91/build.gradle#L64)

Comment: Thanks a lot .I will check , try and will get back to you

Comment: I think for every run this "TestResults/Reports/cucumber-html " will be overwritten. Not sure where to write it once so that for all run the project name is displayed without further changes

Comment: [I do remove old test results here](https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton/blob/f4be403e6fb00d78cc9b4175769b1b8b8177af91/src/test/java/core/setup/Hooks.java#L60). You will have to mess with that if you don't want that functionality

Comment: Just in case if you have latest updated project ( Cucumber +gradle )  on  parallel testing ,please pass on the git repo link

Comment: Just in case if you have latest updated project ( Cucumber +gradle ) on parallel testing ,please pass on the git repo link

Comment: [If you want the latest then you can update the cucumber version here.](https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton/blob/master/build.gradle#L22) You will also have to change around the other spots where the cucumber version is set in the build gradle. ---- [Update the recent gradle wrapper version here](https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton/blob/f4be403e6fb00d78cc9b4175769b1b8b8177af91/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties#L6). The project is as is so you will need to make changes as needed for yourself :)

Comment: @BalajiSingh.Y this is the git repo link https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton.git

Comment: Can you please tell how to override the tags by passing parameter from Command line . For example some like below gradle runTest -PtestTag="@sanity_ui1" -Pplt=local -Penv=stage -Pbrowser=chrome

Comment: **-P** is for project properties you should be using **-D** for system properties

Comment: Use **-DdeviceName=chrome** for changing driver. Checkout the config for system properties to use. https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-gradle-selenium-cucumber-parallel-skeleton/blob/f4be403e6fb00d78cc9b4175769b1b8b8177af91/src/test/java/core/setup/Config.java#L50 @BalajiSingh.Y

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help and info. For UI Tests it very much fine. Can you provide me a working piece of code for  Api parallel execution. For Api I am using Rest Api`s ( HTTPRequest and Http Response ) .Below is the Sample Code that i am using

Comment: import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
 public RequestSpecification get_httpRequest_Ref(String url)
 { System.out.println("Called the Request Specification method");
  httpRequest= null;
  if(httpRequest==null)
  {  System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
   RestAssured.baseURI = url;
   RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
   httpRequest = RestAssured.given().log().all();
         }
  else
  {
    System.out.println(" HttpRequest is not null");
  }
  return httpRequest; }

Comment: : For Api Response public static Response getHttpResponse(String endpoint_path)
 {
  response = httpRequest.get(endpoint_path);
  return response;
 }

Comment: glad to hear it. If this has been helpful could you please select my answer as the solution with some upvotes and starring the project :)

I would suggest using something other than cucumber for api testing. I would **Checkout spock** since I have found that is much better for api testing.

Comment: I have voted for your correct answer and help provided by you. But my project need all stuff (I  mean mobile , ui , api ) in one framework. Hence have to look for an solution here.

Comment: [For mobile you can look here for some help with my other project here.](https://github.com/seanfrenzel/java-selenium-cucumber-appium-skeleton) I won't be able to help further for the API and if you want to use cucumber for that will have to find your own solution if you want to keep using this projects structure. 

I would suggest having the ui, api as their own subprojects in gradle if you need to have an all in one project. *For API checkout Spock or something like Karate which uses Gherkin too.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for sending a note on the mobile part also. Surely will take a look of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And is it possible to add listener to cucumber task?